# your device isn't compatible with this version play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

This is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="***********"
android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"  android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<permission
    android:name="ge.unipay.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<application
    android:name=".UApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/NoTitleBar"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LauncherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="locale"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>






    <activity
        android:name=".activities.welcometutorial.ProductTourActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />




    <receiver
        android:name=".services.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".services.gcm.GcmMessageHandler" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect"
        android:value="ratio_float"/>


    <service
        android:name=".services.CheckEmailVerification"
        android:enabled="true" />


    <service android:name=".firabase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".firabase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>



</application>
```

This is a part code in my build.gradle file

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "********"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 45
    versionName "1.0.44"
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true


    generatedDensities = []
    ndk {
        moduleName "secret-jni"
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
    }
   }
    aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

I have Huawei honor 6  Device and when i run my app from usb then everything working perfect.But i have one problem.I published my app in play store and i can't download it from playstore.The message is

```
your device isn't compatible with this version
```

My device's android version is 4.4.2 and i use min version 15.How i can solve my problem?
P.s
I think,problem is Nfc permission.Huawei does not support NFC.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" android:required="false" />
```